# JSON data appearing as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some valid JSON as follows

```
[
    {
        "userFullName": "Tim, Bill",
        "id": "LOt3",
        "organisation": "FAP",
        "loginSystem": "A",
        "userId": 0
    },
    {
        "userFullName": "Bruce, David",
        "id": "LNA",
        "organisation": "ES",
        "loginSystem": "A",
        "userId": 0
    }
]
```

I am attempting to access the JSON elements in the success of an AJAX call as follows:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log('data ' + data);
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        console.log('id' + data[key].id);
        $('#selectStaff').append('<option value="' + data[key].id + '">' + data[key].id + '</option>');
    });
}
```

But `data[key].id` is returning `undefined` and if I just print out `data[key]`, I get the individual characters of the array.

`selectStaff` is the ID of a `SELECT`.

What am I missing ?? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try console.log(data) to see what the data variable contains

Comment: `typeof data === string`, `typeof($.parseJSON(data)) === object` tada!

Comment: @palaѕн I have tried value.id and have got the same result.

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin console.log(data) gives me the JSON that I have printed in the question

Comment: Please amend your question to show the rest of the ajax call.  You're getting flooded with responses that you need parse data to create an object, when you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well either you have to use `JSON.parse(data)` or add `dataType` option to your ajax function, so it knows the reponse is in JSON format and nothing else.

```
....
 dataType:"json",
success: function (data) {
     javascript: console.log('data ' + data);
     $.each(data, function(key, value) {
     javascript: console.log('id' + data[key].id);
     $('#selectStaff').append('<option value="' + data[key].id+ '">' + data[key].id+ '</option>');
       });
}
```

or

```
 success: function (data) {
     javascript: console.log('data ' + data);
     data=JSON.parse(data);
     $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       .......
```

Comment: I have dataType : json set with the same result. Actually I was using datatype with a lowercase t. Changing it to upper case fixed it. I will accept your answer Bipen.

Comment: welcome... yes i was about to comment on @rory's post.. about that `t` in `dataType`..he had it in samll letters...anyways glad it helped.. happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Atq7K/) when data is defined as an object.

Given that you state:

> if I just print out data[key], I get the individual characters of the array.

it sounds like the result of your `$.ajax` call is returning a string, not deserialised JSON. You can use the `dataType` parameter to force the deserialisation:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    // rest of your settings...
});
```

Comment: I have datatype" 'json'  set in the AJAX call

Comment: Your answer was correct as well as incorrect. I had datatype defined just as put it, but it worked after I changed it to dataType.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

[Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
  console.log( "second complete" );
});
```

(The above is taken from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Not if he specifies the `dataType`

Comment: true. Thats why the first link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ shows how to set datatype to json. I gave three links for @John to see that there are different ways of doing things. Also he will get more idea about whats going on. Good for research.

Answer (score 0):

try parsing json with jquery:

```
success: function (data2) {
    var data=jQuery.parseJSON(data2);
    console.log('data ' + data);
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        console.log('id' + data[key].id);
        $('#selectStaff').append('<option value="' + data[key].id + '">' + data[key].id + '</option>');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **type** of your **data** parameter, you want to receive an object. If it's not an object then you need to parse it.

You can either specify the datatype which handles it for you:

```
$.ajax({
    datatype: 'json',
    // ...
});
```

Or you can parse it manually:

```
if (typeof data === "string") {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
}
```